# Chrome css3 mix blend mode bug in chrome

Tags: html, css, animation

I hav a two overlays which overlap each other and the overlayed part is blended using mix blend mode multiply.
In chrome the effect is applied but there is strange flickering of the div with this property.
whats the reason for this flickering and how it can be solved.
I have tested it on firefox its good running but not in chrome.!

[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/5cvmcc075/)

The above image is once animation gets over and once its done the left div starts blinking continuously.

```
    <div class="bottom-banner wr-fl">
        <div class="left-overlay overlay"></div>
        <div class="right-overlay overlay"></div>
        <div class="center heading">
            {{entry.bottom_banner.banner_heading}}
        </div>
    </div>
    .bottom-banner .left-overlay
    {
        mix-blend-mode:multiply;
        background:rgba(0,54,108,0.7);
        transform:skew(-25deg);
        z-index:11;
        left:-280px;

    }
    .bottom-banner .right-overlay
    {
        width:500px;
        transform:skew(-25deg);
        right:-600px;
        animation:slideinbottom 2s ;
        background:red;
        mix-blend-mode:multiply;
    }
```

Comment: thats my html and css3 code

Comment: Flicker is normally resolved with something like `backface-visibility: hidden;`
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp

Answer (score 19):

I had this issue and found that it seems to be caused by the combination of opacity with mix-blend-mode. The solution was either to add a rule of `will-change: opacity` or alternatively `transform: translateZ(0)` to the parent of the transitioning element. Either one of those will do, but I think the `will-change` option is preferable (in that it's less hacky).

In either case, I think the effect is to hand over painting of that element to the GPU (or at least to warn the browser that it might be repainted), which seems to fix the issue.

Credit due to [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=503638) in the Chromium bug tracker for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This is still an issue in chrome 73 android, which is resolved by this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you test overflow/scrolled content with this. `will-change` gets the blend mode working, but there's a separate bug that causes overflowed content to disappear when mix-blend-mode is used. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798148#c3

Comment: `will-change` worked for me but on the same element, not the parent one. For those who discovered this issue recently there is the bug report on Chromium Bug tracker about this very same issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=961581
This workaround doesn't work for SVG though, unfortunately.

Comment: This fixed an issue for me in Safari, where mix-blend-mode went awol after a rotate.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered an issue with `mix-blend-mode` in latest Chrome (March 2020, Windows 10 x64) 
where the `mix-blend-mode` is simply ignored for elements behind with negative `z-index`. It works correctly in other browsers like Firefox (Stable and Developer Edition) though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue with blend-mode and opacity in the March update, adding will-change fixed it for me.

```css
will-change: opacity;
```

Answer (score -3):

it will work on all browsers try this

```css
.bottom-banner .left-overlay
    {
       -webkit-mix-blend-mode: multiply;
       -moz-mix-blend-mode: multiply;
       -o-mix-blend-mode: multiply;
       -ms-mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        mix-blend-mode:multiply;
        background:rgba(0,54,108,0.7);
        -webkit-transform:skew(-25deg);
        -moz-transform:skew(-25deg);
        -ms-transform:skew(-25deg);
        transform:skew(-25deg);
        z-index:11;
        left:-280px;

    }
    .bottom-banner .right-overlay
    {
        width:500px;
        -webkit-transform:skew(-25deg);
        -moz-transform:skew(-25deg);
        -ms-transform:skew(-25deg);
        transform:skew(-25deg);
        right:-600px;
        -webkit-animation:slideinbottom 2s ;
         -moz-animation:slideinbottom 2s ;
          -ms-animation:slideinbottom 2s ;
           -o-animation:slideinbottom 2s ;
           animation:slideinbottom 2s ;
        background:red;
        -webkit-mix-blend-mode: multiply;
       -moz-mix-blend-mode: multiply;
       -o-mix-blend-mode: multiply;
       -ms-mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        mix-blend-mode:multiply;
    }
```

Comment: The issue is not to do with cross browser compatibility. As the OP shows; the blend mode works in Chrome but there is a flicker.

Comment: blend mode is not supported by IE or Edge at all. It's not a question of compatibility, it's a chrome bug.