# Mix-blend-mode bug on text

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mix-blend-mode

I am working on a knockout text using `mix-blend-mode` property. When I open the console to use Developer tools to test responsiveness, there are little lines that appear and disappear above and below of the blended text. On every selection, I do on the device selector of the developer tools console, this bug is presented. These are some examples:

**Page resized to  iPad Pro size**

[image]

**Page resized to  Pixel 2XL size**

[image]

This is the code I use to create this text:

```css
.backdrop {
  background: url("https://rpsthecoder.github.io/img-repo/Taitō%20by%20Jezael%20Melgoza.jpg") center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 75vw;
}

.text {
  font: bolder 20vw "Arial";
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.screen {
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop">
  <p class="text screen">Taitō</p>
</div>
```

I notice that this bug does not happen when you run the code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lvidal/pen/gOOVENM) and I could not figure out why is that. However, it can happen on a simple static HTML file.

I tried to use `will-change: opacity` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479321/chrome-css3-mix-blend-mode-bug-in-chrome) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140449/mix-blend-mode-doesnt-work-on-chrome), but I had no luck.

My chrome version is **Version 78.0.3904.108**. This bug only happens on Chrome. I would appreciate it if anyone can give advice about this.

Comment: are you including the doctype in your HTML file?

Comment: That's an antialiasing *bug*. You can repro on desktop by translating by fractions of a pixel: https://jsfiddle.net/93daepz0/. You may open an issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list but note that even FF and Safari have the same bug, and that your users on real devices may not face it in  your configuration (since they wouldn't have the weird transform the dev-tools are doing to emulate the different monitors).

Answer (score 2):

If you are result-oriented then this solution might help you to get rid of this issue. I have also checked with `mix-blend-mode` but as you said there is an issue in Chrome.

I have used `background-clip: text` to achieve the same result.

**Page resized to iPad Pro size**

[image]

**Page resized to Pixel 2XL size**

[image]

Please let me know if this helps.

```css
.backdrop {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 75vw;
}
.text {
  font: bolder 20vw "Arial";
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.screen {
  color: transparent;
  background: url("https://rpsthecoder.github.io/img-repo/Taitō%20by%20Jezael%20Melgoza.jpg") center;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="backdrop">
    <p class="text screen">Taitō</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I need to keep with this approach because I need to have the background separated from the text